# lsof +d doesn't work properly on live CD

Tags: ubuntu, livecd, lsof

```
mkdir testdir
cat > testdir/whatever
```

when running from live CD (Ubuntu)

`lsof +d testdir` shows nothing while **cat** is still running

Does it have something to do with overlay fs?
Can the behaviour be fixed with some parameter?